# Why is my app not available to some devices via Market?

Tags: android

As a specific example, the app is not available to the HTC Wildfire S. This device is listed in Android Market publisher console as one of the devices that it IS available to, but the web Market shows the app and the Wildfire as incompatible. Which is obviously confusing. the app is not available to a whole range of devices including the Galaxy S, the Galaxy S2, the Galaxy Ace, even though these are also showing in the Market console as compatible.

Here's the relevant manifest settings as shown in the Market:

Screen layouts: SMALL NORMAL LARGE XLARGE

Required device features

android.hardware.wifi

android.hardware.screen.landscape

android.hardware.touchscreen

The app is paid, and is available to all countries so I do not think this is a country issue.

What am I missing? Android Market says the app is available to these devices, so why is it not? I am struggling to understand why one side of the Android Market says it's compatible, but the public-facing side says it's not. What's going on?

Comment: Do you have 'Copy Protection' enabled in the market?

Comment: Did you verify that the app does not show up in the market when the market is accessed from a Wildfire or one of the other compatible/incompatible devices?

Comment: Copy Protection is Off. The app is not visible on the Wildfire itself in Android Market.

Comment: I notice that if I search for the publisher (my client) in Android Market on the Wildfire it responds with "3 results" but if I click through to see them, only two are shown (i.e. the one I'm having trouble with is taken into account to total the matches, but the listing isn't shown. What a mess.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, If your app target version is not compatible with the device OS version, app won't show up for download.

Comment: The app has a minSdkVersion of 8 (v2.2), and the Wildfire is running v2.35 so I do not think OS versions are the issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you've turned on encryption then this can cause an issue with some of Googles licenses with OEMs.

An example of this is the T-Mobile Pulse which will simply not display apps which have been encrypted.

Cheers,
Matt

Comment: I guess you mean encryption as in Proguard? The app has not been run through Proguard. It has Android licensing in it (not the old copy protection) but I don't imagine that's the problem. Hmm.

Comment: No I am referring to the encryption you apply on the market submission page

Answer (score 1):

From what I know, all the Market filtering is carried away using the Manifest. So Proguard can't be the issue. I imagine that your app can be installed manually on your Wildfire. It may be a bug of the Market filtering for some uncommon features AND devices. For example, the `android.hardware.screen.landscape` is unnecessary for your device (since the doc states that your device is supposed to accept both [[1](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html)]). Maybe you can try to release your next update with a device specific apk for API level <= 12 and without this requirement, and see if it appears.

You also have to take market caching in consideration, and it can take a few hours for the new version to appear on your device (even if you erase the Market App data).

Comment: I don't think it's a caching issue, it's been going on for several days. There's nothing in the manifest that is causing this filtering - everything in the manifest is benign. I agree the landscape entry is superfluous, but it's not causing this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Have you verified that the users have all checkboxes checked under settings->content filtering? I've experienced some users where default is that none of them were checked resulting in my app not being visible even though I have the lowest level, i.e no age limit.

Comment: On a device I have here the app is not visible in Market, but the content filtering settings in Market are set to show everything. So this is not the cause as far as I can see.

Comment: A meta question, should I remove my comment, vote it down or what since it been confirmed not being valid for this question?

Answer (score 1):

I see from Google+ (That's cheating, I know) that your app is 37MB. AFAIK certain devices - especially Samsung - tend to flat out reject applications if they are too large. Try to shrink your application footprint (as a test, if it works you could download the app data as a separate package post install) and see if that does the trick.

Edit: 2DBoy wrote about how they had this issue [here](http://2dboy.com/2011/11/28/world-of-goo-now-available-on-android/).